# Error code using Linq to add to a variable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'll start with the problem, and then describe how the procedure works.

I'm getting a an error saying:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group)' cannot be converted to 'LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group'.

The blue underline pinpointing the problem is on `Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r` on the right side of the operator.

I know it is something to do with explicitness

--

This is for a table top card game i am converting to a text game.

The goal of this sub procedure is to subtract a card from a players hand and add it to the discard pile. Once added to the discard pile I then call the discard pile to move the cards from the discard pile to the card deck.

The problem starts with the number generator.
What I'm doing is randomly picking a card from the deck. by generating a the card id of a card in the deck. Once the ID is generated using linq the number generated then takes a card, then adds the card to the players inventory (quantity integer), and subtracts from the deck.

T represents whose turn it is. Currently for testing purposes I have coded it for only 2 players in terms of the T variable.

```
  Private Sub GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
        Dim CardCheckBoxInteger As Integer
        'ReDeclare CheckBox Array for Private sub
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
        'Discard
        Select Case T
            Case 0
                Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger -= 1
            Case 1
                Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger2 -= 1
            Case 2
                Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger3 -= 1
            Case 3
                Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger4 -= 1
            Case 4
                Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger5 -= 1
        End Select
        'Add Card to Discard Pile
        DiscardGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger += 1
        'Shuffle Deck from Discard Pile if Deck is out of cards
        Call DiscardPile()
        'Reset Number Generator, unless weapon isn't discard
        Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In DeckGroup Where r.QuantityInteger > 0 Select r

        If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.count > 0 Then
            Number = (temp(Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
            ' ** Edit **: This will give you the actual object to be manipulated
            Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = (From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r).Single


            Dim PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger As Integer
            For PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB
                ' ** Edit **
                obj.QuantityInteger -= 1
                'Select the Player depending value of T
                Select Case T
                    Case 0
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
                    Case 1
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 += 1
                    Case 2
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3 += 1
                    Case 3
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 += 1
                    Case 4
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 += 1
                End Select
                CardTypeArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                NumberArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Number
            Next PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger
        End If

        'Switch to next player
        Select Case T
            Case 0
                For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                    CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(CardCheckBoxInteger + 5)).CardNameString
                Next
                T += 1
            Case 1
                If GameSize = 2 Then
                    For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                        CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(CardCheckBoxInteger)).CardNameString
                    Next CardCheckBoxInteger
                    T -= 1
                End If
                If GameSize > 2 Then
                    T += 1
                End If
            Case 2
            Case 3
            Case 4

        End Select
        Label1.Text = T.ToString

        'Clear Check Boxes when turn is finished
        For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
            CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Checked = False
        Next

        'Turn off play button
        PlayButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
From r In temp 
Where r.ID = Number 
Select r
```

Returns a collection of everything which matches the `Where` clause (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) for the MSDN documentation). .NET represents this as an IEnumerable, which means a collection of things which can be iterated over (e.g. using a `For` loop or something like that).

There is no automatic concept that you'll only get one record returned even though your condition is an `=` (there may also be conditions, broadly, where no elements are returned such as when nothing matches the equality condition or where multiple things match the equality condition).

In order to indicate that you only want one element you can use the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx), [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) methods.

For example:

```
 Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = (From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r).Single()
```

Which will give you an object of type `LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group`, which I think you're looking for in this case.

As an aside, it's not bad to know the difference between the methods I've outlined above. In my lay perspective (as I'm no expert):

- `First` returns the first item in the collection or throws an Exception if the collection is empty
- `FirstOrDefault` returns the first item in the collection or null if empty
- `Single` returns the only item in the collection or throws an Exception if the collection does not have exactly one item
- `SingleOrDefault` returns the first item in the collection, null if the collection is empty and throws an exception if the collection has more than 1 element

So in your case, since you should only match on a single item with the `=` condition I would suggest using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

**PS.** Sorry, when I say `null` above, that'll be `Nothing` in VB.NET speak

Comment: Now when I play a card, it adds +5 of a random card instead. So now in my players array holding the cards he theoretically has 9 cards. When the players plays their card, it remoces card played (like it is suppose to), retaining the 4 remaining in the hand, then adds 5 of the new card. The 5 checkboxes I have representing cards are filled with these 5 cards.

The goal is remove 1 card from inventory and play into discard pile, remove 1 random card from the deck and add to the players hand. So overall the code does everything, except take the correct amount of the random card.

Comment: I think you will need to post your full source code if you need more help as I'm not sure where some things in your code are coming from. However, I suspect that the issue is because of your For loop `For PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB` and how you are adding and removing quantities inside it

Comment: should I edit the question, or somehow message you the sourcecode?

Comment: Please edit the question. If you have downloadable source code I am can take a look if you provide a link but I don't know know the SO etiquette around these things as I'm still new to the site

Comment: Ok added the change to the edit. I've tried `obj.QuantityInteger -= 1` located in the loop and out of the loop (`For PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB`).

Comment: Where to the values for `ChecksDynamicA` and `ChecksDynamicB` come from? What are they set to when you run through the loop (e.g. if you debug through your code what are their values, how many times does the loop run etc)

Comment: They are 0 to 4 for player 1, and 5 to 9 for player 2. This loop represents the slots of the player's cards in the player's hand. So 0 and 5 are card 1, 1 and 6 being card 2, etc.

Comment: OK, so let's say I am Player 1 (I assume this is T = 0)...this means `ChecksDyanmicA = 0` and `ChecksDynamicB = 4`. So your For loop will execute 5 times, each time subtracting one from the quanity of the random card because of `obj.QuantityInteger -= 1` (for a total of reducing the quantity by 5) and it will add 5 of that random cardto Player 1's hand because of `Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1` being in the `For` loop...is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: It is expected to give me just one of a single random card where the cards deckgroup.quantityinteger is > 0 (not empty).

Comment: Then the reason it is executing 5 times is because you're in the `For` loop. If you only want one card then I don't think the For loop is required at all

Comment: I tried taking the select case outside of the for loop. The results were. It successfully adds a card to the players hand. and adds the old to the discard. But now it doesnt subtract from the text, and the new card is repeated across the checkboxes. (the repeation across the textboxes may be from the loop still wrapped around the cardtypearray and cardcheckboxarray. But my little summary box tells me which cards are actually in my hands.

Comment: Sorry, I think with the kind of detail you're getting into and the fact I don't have the full code for your app it's really difficult. I'd like to help you more but I think I really need to see your entire application in front of me - the continued comments back and forth probably aren't helping you or me too much...as I said before, if you have it available I am more than happy to help you. I think, perhaps, you're just getting started on your programming journey and it's good to help people when they are getting started

Comment: I think I figured it out. I took out the loop, took out the ob.quantityinteger - 1 and changed it to the `deckgroup(number).quantityinteger` The loop was there from when I used a different method for generating the needed card.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting us know. This question has gotten a bit long so it's perhaps best to open another SO question if you need more assistance with your program....and it's good to see that people are still playing Lunch Money nowadays